# How do you actually implement the Search Contract? (C#)

Tags: c#, search, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm having some trouble understanding and getting the search contract to work in my Store app. I have been unable to find any sort of documentation or guide that explains the structure of using the contract. (I've looked at the quickstarts on MSDN, the Search Contract sample and the build video, but that only really deals with javascript)

So far I've been able to run a query and get a list (of Custom Objects) into my search contract page, and from there I try to assign that to defaultviewmodel.results, but no matter what query I type nothing shows up I on the page. Is there something else I need to set?
What I have so far is as follows (excerpts):

App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnSearchActivated(Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.SearchActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            SearchCharmResultsPage.Activate(args.QueryText, args.PreviousExecutionState);
            SearchCharmResultsPage.ProcessSearchQuery(args.QueryText);
        }    


public async static void ProcessSearchQuery(string queryString)
        {
            try
            {
                StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("recipeCustomObject                  Debug.WriteLine("Database exists, connecting");
                SQLiteAsyncConnection connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("CustomObject_db");
                List<CustomObject> resultsList = new List<CustomObject>();
                string query = "SELECT * FROM CustomObjectDB";
                resultsList =  await connection.QueryAsync<RecipeRecord>(query);  
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException fnfExc)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("FNFEXC: " + fnfExc.ToString());
            }
        }
```

I think it is possible that here lies the problem, though I'm not sure if it is, or how to change it.
the resultsList list is created here, but because the method it asynchronous, I can't return from the method. Because of this I'm guess that when I try to assign `this.DefaultViewModel[Results] = resultsList;` in the LoadStateMethod, the object doesn't exist (thought the program throws no error). When I try to add the same line in the `ProcessSearchQuery` method, i'm told that `this` is not valid in a static method, but I think I need the method to be static? My problem might just be a fundamental logic error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it! found the solution here: http://jeffblankenburg.com/2012/11/06/31-days-of-windows-8-day-6-search-contract

For those looking for an answer in the future, the key is to make sure you have your search logic within the `Filter_SelectionChanged` method, which was something I wasn't doing. Look at the guide within the above link to get an idea of the structure.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [Search contract sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Search-app-contract-sample-118a92f5) on the developer center?  There's a C#/XAML version there as well.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, I have done this too, and while I can see how that particular example works, I don't find it particularly useful, mainly because to prove that the query is handled it simply displays the query you typed on the page, instead of e.g. a set of sample results on a search results page.

Comment: yeah that sample is a bit lean... the gist of it is to use OnSearchActivated to navigate to a new search result page, where you then process the query args to arrive at yo

Comment: [got cut off :(] yeah that sample is a bit lean... the gist of it is to use OnSearchActivated to navigate to a new search result page, where you then process the query args to arrive at your results, which you display with your result page in whatever format you like.  Zubair's been kind enough to share his full implementation so hopefully that will fill in gaps.

Comment: thanks, I see what you mean. Based on what I have already done (shown above), I think I have done those steps. Like I mentioned, I am able to get the list I want to display, but I setting it as results in the `DefaultViewModel` doesn't work. I suspect its a data encapsulation kind of problem (a method access a variable or something), but I need someone to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

My open source Win8 RSS Reader framework implements Search (and Share) have a look at the source and if you still got questions, I'll be happy to help http://win8rssreader.codeplex.com/

Comment: thank you for showing me your code. Seeing it has given me a good insight into how it should be done...most disappointing however, I'm sure that I have gone through all the basic steps of populating your results List, and setting this to `DefaultViewModel["Results"]` that you have!! I am at a complete loss as to what to do.