# search contract within the Metro app of Windows8

Tags: search, windows-8, microsoft-metro, charms-bar

I would like to know how can I implement the search contract from within the app, to search/find a few files present inside the application.

As far as I know, there are a lot of articles especially from msdn, blogs, etc which helps us create a normal search contract to search/look for apps/books, etc on win8 system, but I have not come across any valuable source for implementing search within the app.

Your response will eb of great help to me :) Thanks in advance..!

Comment: You want to capture search event (triggered by user querying something) while your app is the main app on screen or isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, you can add a search contract using **Add a New Item** command in Visual Studio. The IDE will register the appropriate handlers to catch `QuerySubmitted` event or `Search Activated` events. The former is used for capturing search event while your application is the main app on screen and the second one is for situations where your application is not running as the active app.

What you search in your application isn't important. It's completely your own business. You can search for files inside your apps or anything else.

Recently I've read an article on MSDN about this. Maybe useful for you too

[Adding search to an app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868180.aspx)

Also similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195477/how-do-you-actually-implement-the-search-contract-c) on StackOverflow

Comment: thanx a ton @moghaddam..!! I am referring to the prescribed articles and I hope i figure out the solution..!

Comment: Also, it looks like http://jeffblankenburg.com/2012/11/06/31-days-of-windows-8-day-6-search-contract is also a good sample for me to start with..!!

Comment: ok..This works now..!! But is there any way to add a search index within an app? say, for instance, search with A-E, F-K, and so on..?

Comment: What do you mean by adding a search index? Do you have some data inside your app which needs to be indexed to make finding results faster?